# How to replay all events from the start?

Tags: bsc, binance

I want to replay all events on a [bsc](/questions/tagged/bsc) chain and index them.

If I understand correctly, the only way of doing this at the moment would be to call [`getBlock(0)`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#getblock) and go from there, checking every transaction one by one.

Is that correct?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I also looked into `subscribe('logs')` but even though you can specific `fromBlock: 0` it only starts from the block it is actually syncing

Answer (score 0):

I've measured latency / throughput of different methods, and found that the most efficient way to replay all the logs is using [`web3.eth.getPastLogs`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html).

Comment: Related question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/100195/how-to-define-multiple-topics