# How to define multiple topics?

Tags: web3js

As an example, [`getPastLogs`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#getpastlogs) defines `topics` parameter as:

> topics - Array: An array of values which must each appear in the log entries. The order is important, if you want to leave topics out use null, e.g. `[null, '0x12...']`. You can also pass an array for each topic with options for that topic e.g. `[null, ['option1', 'option2']]`

If I mean reading this right, then:

- `['0x12...']` will filter by `0x12...` topic.
- `[null, '0x12...']` will match all topics, and filter by index parameters.

I don't comprehend the `[null, ['option1', 'option2']]` example though.

Currently, I am doing it as such:

```js
const [syncLogs, swapLogs] = await Promise.all([
  web3.eth.getPastLogs({
    fromBlock: firstBlockNumber,
    toBlock: firstBlockNumber,
    topics: [
      syncToken.signature,
    ],
  }),
  web3.eth.getPastLogs({
    fromBlock: firstBlockNumber,
    toBlock: firstBlockNumber,
    topics: [
      swapToken.signature,
    ],
  }),
]);
```

Though this results in two distinct JSON-RPC calls.

Is there a way to filter by multiple topics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[null, ['option1', 'option2']]` means the first topic can be anything, the second topic has to be either `'option1'` or `'option2'`.

Comment: I am asking if there is a way to filter all logs by multiple first topics.

Comment: @Gajus Did you try something like `[['topic1','topic2']]`? In general topics are good enough for simple queries, for more complex you should use an indexer or something more advanced like graphql.

Comment: I am basically interested in all `Sync` and `Swap` events. The approach that I've shared in the original post works, I was simply wondering if I could pull the same data using a single call.

Comment: @Gajus Can you try something like `topics: [
      [syncToken.signature, swapToken.signature]
    ],`? The system underneath uses bloom filters for topics, it has some use cases, but it has its own limitations.

Comment: Your last suggestion does indeed what I was looking for. Thank you!